# Simple Powershell script to get file from FTP

Tags: powershell, ftp

so I've been trying to figure out this script to try and get a daily file uploaded to our FTP server. I've used this script in the past with success since the files are uploaded with a consistent file name:
IE: FILE_NAME_2016-05-25.csv (Where the current days date is always formatted like this)

So this works when the file name maintains this consistency, but I need to use it to get a file that has an inconsistent value, appended to the end.
IE: FILE_NAME_2016-05-25_0503 (The last value never being consistent).

So is there a way to use a wildcard character at the end of the file/folder variable to account for this?

My code (Note I am very new to powershell)

```
#Get's file from the FTP using today's date
Write-Host "Please wait while your file downloads"
$server = "ftp.server.net" 
$user = "user"
$pass = "pass"
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$localpath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$TodayDate = (get-date)
$FileNameDate = date $TodayDate -f yyyy-MM-dd
$remotefilepath = "inbox/sub1/sub2/FILE_NAME_$FileNameDate_[*].txt"
$localfilename = "FILE_NAME_$FileNameDate.csv"
$localfilelocation = "$localpath\$localfilename"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)
$uri = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$server/$remotefilepath”)
$webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $localfilelocation)
```

I tried to use a wildcard character at the end but it appears I am doing something wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming; it's about how to find files by wildcard with FTP commands. Try [su]?

Comment: I'm using this script to automate the processing and downloading of a file from an FTP to import into a SQL server. Normally we would use SSIS to do this, but because we don't have a license for MSSQL we have to go about it different ways. My apologies, but I thought that powershell scripts and automation tasks were part of the programming umbrella for stackoverflow

Comment: My point was that your script seems to work fine for sending FTP commands, you just don't know which commands to send. I'm still not certain it's on-topic, but I'm not certain it's off-topic either so I've retracted my close vote and I'll let others decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try this.

```
Write-Host "Please wait while your file downloads"

#Function to get all files
function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials)
{
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Credentials = $credentials
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream()
    $readline = $reader.ReadLine()
    $output = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    while ($readline -ne $null)
    {
        $output.Add($readline)
        $readline = $reader.ReadLine()
    }
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
    $output
}

$server = "ftp.server.net"
$user = "user"
$pass = "pass"
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$localpath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$TodayDate = (get-date)
$FileNameDate = date $TodayDate -f yyyy-MM-dd
$remotefilepath = "inbox/sub1/sub2"
$localfilename = "FILE_NAME_$FileNameDate.csv"
$localfilelocation = "$localpath\$localfilename"
$uri = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$server/$remotefilepath”)

#List of all files on FTP-Server
$files = Get-FTPDir $uri -credentials (New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass))

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    if ($file -like "FILE_NAME_$($FileNameDate)_*.txt")
    {
        $file
        $fileuri = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$server/$remotefilepath/$file”)
        $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)
        $webclient.DownloadFile($fileuri, $localfilelocation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works like a charm!! I also feel somewhat accomplished that my own research was leading me down to the IO.Streamreader and read line method to pull the data from a stream. This whole thing has been a rather interesting learning experience, but thank you!

Comment: Hi.. for me its failing and saying remote server requires ssl. can you please help me in estabilishing connection with https

Comment: if anyone runs into the "protocol violation" error in .NET 4.5, read this article and try the first suggestion. The rest of the article explains the issue. :https://bhargavs.com/index.php/2014/03/17/ignoring-ssl-trust-in-powershell-using-system-net-webclient/

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using [WinSCP's .Net library](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), which provides a more complete set of FTP commands.  Or you could use [FtpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx), which also provides the functionality you're looking for since you can enumerate the remote files and then get the ones you want, but might be more cumbersome to use since all data transfers are streams.  C# code is pretty portable to PowerShell, but it might be a bit steep for someone new so you might want to stick to WinSCP's .Net library.

Another alternative is to build a script file and use `ftp.exe` to get it.  [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555976) is an old doc that tells you what to do.  You'll want to use the `mget` command instead.  One drawback is that you've got to write the password to a text file, but, well, you technically already do that anyways since it's in your PowerShell script.  You could do something like:

```
Set-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "open ""ftp://$server/$remotefilepath"""
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "$user"
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "$pass"
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "cd ""inbox/sub1/sub2/"""
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "lcd ""$localpath"""
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "bin"
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "mget ""FILE_NAME_$FileNameDate_[*].txt"""
Add-Content -Path $FtpScriptFile -Encoding ASCII -Value "bye"
C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe -s:"$FtpScriptFile"
```

(Note: I have not tested that at all, and it's not necessarily the best way to do this.)

---

Additionally, a lot of your script could be optimized.  You're doing some backflips to get some simple values.  `(Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value` is the same thing as `$MyInvocation`.  The only reason you might need Get-Variable is to list assigned variables and to use dynamic variables -- that is, variables whose names you don't know until runtime... variable variable names.

This:

```
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$localpath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$TodayDate = (get-date)
$FileNameDate = date $TodayDate -f yyyy-MM-dd
```

Can just be:

```
$LocalPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$FileNameDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

I also wonder if this is what's causing you problems:

```
$remotefilepath = "inbox/sub1/sub2/FILE_NAME_$FileNameDate_[*].txt"
```

When I have that in PowerShell ISE, it looks like the system thinks the variable is `$FileNameDate_`.  Try:

```
$remotefilepath = "inbox/sub1/sub2/FILE_NAME_$($FileNameDate)_[*].txt"
```

That's how most people write it.

Personally, I'd probably write your script like so:

```
$RemoteFilePath = 'inbox/sub1/sub2/FILE_NAME_{0}_[*].txt' -f $FileNameDate
$LocalFileName = 'FILE_NAME_{0}.csv' -f $FileNameDate
$LocalFileLocation = Join-Path -Path $LocalPath -ChildPath $LocalFileName
```

That's using the format operator (see `Get-Help about_Operators -ShowWindow`) and the Join-Path cmdlet.  I find it easier to read.

Comment: Awesome thanks for all the advice. I've used your advice to at least trim down and make my script more efficient. Unfortunately, it appears that even though your advice fixed the system variable issues with the file name, it's still outputting FILE_NAME_2016-05-25_[*] with a "File not found" error. So I'll dig around in those links you gave me and try and find another way to do this, since I don't think FTP requests handle the wildcards like local files do in powershell

Comment: @mattlore No, they do.  That's what the `mget` and `mput` commands are for.  Run `ftp.exe` interactively.  you might need to use the command `mget  FILE_NAME_2016-05-25_*.*`.